# Trying SSH into an Amazon EC2 instance(windows server2012) from windows 7 - permission denied

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, cygwin, putty

this is probably a simple stupidly question :)

I've created a new windows instance on Amazon EC2, and also downloaded the .pem file to SSH.

with cygwin

```
 $ ssh -i mykey.pem Administrator@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    Administrator@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com's password:
    Permission denied, please try again.
```

permission set to 400 for mykey.pem file.

```
$ chmod 400 mykey.pem
```

I also tired with the putty by creating mykey.ppk file form mykey.pem with puttygen but getting access denied error :(

```
 Using username "Administrator".
 Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
 Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
 Administrator@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com's password:
 Access denied
```

dont know what kind of silly mistake im making here! 
Please guys do u have any suggestion here?

Comment: If you create a fresh test EC2 instance and follow [this guide](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2), are you able to connect?

Comment: The *"Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!"* message sounds bad, you should never get this.

Comment: thanks guys!! problem solved. it was a firewall issue!!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH port on EC2 server were not open to incoming traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the most possible reasons-

1. Port 22 is not open while creating EC2 instance
2. Firewall configuration on your local machine(just try disconnecting VPN)
3. AWS account is suspended due to pending bill payment